Inequality for log-convex functions
Let $s:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$ be a positive, decreasing, log-convex function such that $s(0)=1$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}s(x) = 0$. In addition, $-s'$ is also assumed to be log-convex.
Are these assumptions sufficient to show that the inequality
\begin{equation}
\frac{s''(y)}{s'(y)} - \frac{s''(x)}{s'(x)} <   \frac{s(x)}{s(y)} \left(\frac{s'(y)}{s(y)}  - \frac{s''(y)}{s'(y)} \right)
\end{equation}
holds for any $x<y$, or do I need an additional hypothesis ?
Note: The function $s:x \mapsto (1+x)^{-2}$ is one example of such function for which this inequality is valid.
Thanks for the help!
